# on click event does not work when trying to update image by clicking existing image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I have a profile page where a user can update their profile picture. I have added a jQuery on click event on the image. However, when the image is clicked it doesn't show the file upload window to select an image.

This is my CustomerDetailsViewModel profile picture property:

```
public IFormFile ProfilePicture { get; set; }
```

Here is my elements in the razor view:

```
@model CustomerDetailsViewModel

@{
    var imagePath = "~/Images/" + (Model.ProfilePicture?.FileName ?? "noimage.png");
}

<form asp-action="UpdateDetails">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProfilePicture" class="profile-picture-upload" />
    <img src="@imagePath" asp-append-version="true" class="profile-picture" style="height:50px; width:50px"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
<script src="~/js/fileUpload.js"></script>
}
```

Here is my jQuery on click event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.profile-picture', function () {
        $('.profile-picture-upload').click();
    });
})
```

Is this a asp.net core issue or jquery issue? I don't get why this wouldn't work, I have the property in the view model set to IFormFile.

Comment: This is a JS issue. However all your code does is trigger a click on a `hidden` input, which has no effect on anything. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I want it to show the file selection window when the image is clicked, so the user can choose a new image. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: You need to trigger a click on a `file` input then, not a hidden one

Comment: Removing the hidden type fixes the on click issue but now profile-picture element is visible, I don't want this, I just want to be able to click .profile-image and store file in .profile-image-upload @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Changing the type of an unrelated element wouldn't by itself make the image visible. However, you can hide the file input using CSS `display: none`